# how to quantitatively parse through 10,000 page word document

Tags: ms-word, data-analysis

I downloaded all my chrome browser history and came out to be 10,640 pages with 1088878 words. I want to do a quantative data analysis but i do not know where to start. attached is a photo and I only want specific details such as the one in blue (the search option or the website option).
[this is what one of the pages look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQEe1.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for answering specific questions about specific code that already exists. Your question is likely to elicit opinions instead.

Comment: You could parse what you've posted with just two wildcard Find/Replace operations. No code required. Hence, this isn't a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).